# Sidekiq: increase number of jobs executed in parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

If I have a lot of jobs queued, by default, it looks like Sidekiq is running up to 5 jobs in parallel.

How can I increase this number ? 
I'd like to be able to run 10 or 15 jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to edit the sidekiq.yml file with:

```
:concurrency: 25
```

Comment: `sidekiq -c 25` might be useful too.